# Multiple timezones, current time in each moment.js

Tags: jquery, timestamp, momentjs

I'm trying to get my head around Moment JS and the time zone add on.

I would like to get the current time for each office to neatly display in my footer, but not sure where to start.

[Hopefull outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWj5d.png)

```html
<div id="time">
<ul>
  <li><a href="/offices/london">London</a>
    <span class="time">09.00</span> 
  </li>
  <li><a href="/offices/london">Paris</a>
     <span class="time">10.00</span>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/offices/munich">Munich</a>
  <span class="time">10.00</span>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/offices/milan">Milan</a>
  <span class="time">10.00</span>
  </li>
    <li><a href="/offices/moscow">Moscow</a>
  <span class="time">11.00</span>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/offices/dubai">Dubai</a>
  <span class="time">12.00</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note, you also have `/offices/london` the Paris link.

Answer (score 2):

Use:
[Moment.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js) and [moment timezone](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js)

```
$('#London').text(moment.tz('Europe/London').format('HH:mm'));
$('#Paris').text(moment.tz('Europe/Paris').format('HH:mm'));
$('#Berlin').text(moment.tz('Europe/Berlin').format('HH:mm'));
$('#Rome').text(moment.tz('Europe/Rome').format('HH:mm'));
$('#Moscow').text(moment.tz('Europe/Moscow').format('HH:mm'));
$('#Dubai').text(moment.tz('Asia/Dubai').format('HH:mm'));
```

Munich and Milan are not in moment.js data. Instead, use Berlin and Rome.

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uq99udc9/1419/)